Fragment pop out until starting fragment as activity recreated after being destroyed to reclaim resources in background
I save instances state in activity so that i have my session data and restore this data in onCreate through the bundle.
But their is unexpected behaviour in fragment, suppose at start my back stack is A -> B -> C and at C fragment i minimise my app, and wait for android to stop/destroy my activity (check through logs), so now when i open my app my activity recreates but it first show C fragment and after loading it, it pop it out to B then pop to A . i am not pressing any back button or nothing.
inside onCreate
if (savedInstanceState != null) {


            Constant.userId = savedInstanceState.getString(Constant.USER_ID, "0")
            Constant.name = savedInstanceState.getString(Constant.USER_NAME, "NA")
            Constant.phoneNo = savedInstanceState.getString(Constant.PHONE_NUMBER, "NA")
            Constant.email = savedInstanceState.getString(Constant.EMAIL, "NA")
            

        }

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        outState.putString(Constant.USER_ID, Constant.userId)
        outState.putString(Constant.USER_NAME, Constant.name)
        outState.putString(Constant.PHONE_NUMBER, Constant.phoneNo)
        outState.putString(Constant.EMAIL, Constant.email)

    }

I am using navigation component and below is its xml


            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/navController"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/grocery_nav_graph" />


Search stack overflow for this, also have a long chat with AI bots no such case found
